# Applying function and spreading data in dplyr mutate/summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to compute some function and then spread my data based on the results.

Code & Data:

-- Preprocessing:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tsfeatures)

data(FANG)

FANG_returns <- FANG %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select     = adjusted, 
               mutate_fun = periodReturn, 
               period     = "daily", 
               type       = "arithmetic")

FANG_returns
```

Code which works:

```
FANG_returns %>%
  filter(symbol == "FB") %>%
  mutate(ent = entropy(daily.returns))
```

Code which doesn't work:

```
FANG_returns %>%
  filter(symbol == "FB") %>%
  mutate(max = max_level_shift(daily.returns))
```

Error:

> Error: Column `max` must be length 1008 (the group size) or one, not 2

The function `max_level_shift` returns two columns:

```
max_level_shift(AirPassengers)
#>  max_level_shift time_level_shift 
#>             54.5            117.0
```

How can I `spread` my data such that I have my data in the following way:

```
> FANG_returns %>%
+   filter(symbol == "FB") %>%
+   summarise(ent = entropy(daily.returns))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  symbol   ent   max_level_shift time_level_shift
  <chr>  <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>
1 FB     0.991       0.0573yyy       0.92764zzzz
```

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `spread`, we can just subset `max_level_shift(daily.returns)` by positions, as we know *max* will be in the first position and *time* in the 2nd position.

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tsfeatures)
FANG_returns %>%
filter(symbol == "FB") %>%
summarise(ent = entropy(daily.returns) ,
          max_level_shift = max_level_shift(daily.returns)[1], 
          time_level_shift = max_level_shift(daily.returns)[2])

# A tibble: 1 x 4
   symbol   ent max_level_shift time_level_shift
   <chr>  <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 FB     0.991          0.0484              141

#2nd option 
FANG_returns %>%
filter(symbol == "FB") %>%
summarise(ent = entropy(daily.returns) , 
          max = paste(max_level_shift(daily.returns), collapse = '-')) %>% 
separate(max, into=c('max_level_shift','time_level_shift'), sep = '-', convert = TRUE)
```